# Does the member access operator (.) have a higher precedence than the null conditional member access operator (?.)?

Tags: c#, .net

I think we all agree that the null conditional member access operator `?.` introduced with C# 6.0 is pretty handy.

But there is one thing I keep wondering about. Given the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething(Foo foo)
    {
        var knownIndices = new[] { 42 };
        bool overlaps;

        // might throw a null reference exception
        overlaps = foo.Indices.Overlaps(knownIndices);

        // how I used to do it
        overlaps = foo != null && foo.Indices != null && foo.Indices.Overlaps(knownIndices);

        // with null conditional member access (won't compile)
        //overlaps = foo?.Indices?.Overlaps(knownIndices).GetValueOrDefault();

        // with null conditional member access (using local variable)
        bool? overlapsOrIsIndeterminable = foo?.Indices?.Overlaps(knownIndices);
        overlaps = overlapsOrIsIndeterminable.GetValueOrDefault();

        // with null conditional member access (inlined)
        overlaps = (foo?.Indices?.Overlaps(knownIndices)).GetValueOrDefault();

        // with null conditional member access and null-coalescing
        overlaps = foo?.Indices?.Overlaps(knownIndices) ?? false;
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public HashSet<int> Indices;
    }
}
```

Why do I have to use parentheses in the chained expression? `?.Overlaps()` clearly evaluates to a nullable bool as we can see in the example using a local variable so I would expect `.GetValueOrDefault()` to be compilable.

[The C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) states that the member access operator `.` and the null conditional member access operator `?.` are both primary operators and thus share the same precedence level.

Does `.` despite of what is stated in the language reference have a higher precedence than `?.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does . despite of what is stated in the language reference have a higher precedence than ?.?

The null-conditional operator is kind of a special case. Like Dave explained, any consecutive expressions to the right of the `?.` operator are not evaluated if the expression to the left of the operator evaluates to `null`. If the result of the entire expression containing the `?.` operator would normally evaluate to a primitive value (eg `int`), it will actually evaluate to a `Nullable<int>` value, but this value is **not** available to the right hand side of the operator. To the right of the operator you can assume the value is not null (which is the power of the null-conditional operator).

While `foo.GetIntValue()` returns `int`, `foo?.GetIntValue()` returns `Nullable<int>`. If you append to this expression, the "target" value is of type `int`, not `Nullable<int>`. Therefore the following code does not compile, because `GetValueOrDefault` is a member of `Nullable<int>`, not of `int`.

```
foo?.GetIntValue().GetValueOrDefault(); // ERROR
```

Because the *entire* expression does evaluate to a `Nullable<int>`, adding brackets does allow you to call `GetValueOrDefault`.

```
(foo?.GetIntValue()).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Note you can seamlessly combine this operator with the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
foo?.GetIntValue() ?? 1; // If foo is null, this expression will evaluate to 1
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. If one operation in a chain of conditional member access and index operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s execution stops. In the following example, E doesn't execute if A, B, or C evaluates to null.

C#

Copy
A?.B?.C?.Do(E);
A?.B?.C?[E];